# Access Forbidden! Error 403

Tags: configuration, xampp, localhost

I just reformat my pc and installed *XAMPP 1.8.3* in a 64 bit *Windows 7* platform.
I put my project in *htdocs* and run it in Browser.
My project's function saves offenses to a student but when I clicked the `Save Changes` button in the *addedit_offense.php* file in my project, it says:

```
Access Forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object.
It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

Before everything went wrong and before I reformat my PC, everything went well. It runs okay and fine.

Please help me, I've been looking everywhere in the web but can't seem to find the right solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: is there any .htaccess within your project where it is located? is it located beside of the page your are accessing? what the .htaccess contains?

Comment: Hi Mahan! The .htaccess is found inside the "forbidden" folder inside the htdocs where project is saved.

Comment: The .htaccess file contains: 
AuthType Basic
AuthName "FORBIDDEN AREA"
AuthUserFile "../htdocs/forbidden/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

Answer (score 0):

ok as far as you said in the comments, the .htacess causes the problem. try to remove the .htacess file and it will surely work fine

Comment: Hi mahan! I just tried removing the .htaccess file but I still get the same error, I even tried removing the whole "forbidden" folder but still the same. :(

Comment: what is the location of the file you are trying to access? is the file you are trying to access has a near htacess?, after removing an htacess please try to restart the server

Comment: Yes both forbbiden folder and my project are located in htdocs. I tried restarting the server, still the same. I also restarted the laptop, but still the same. There is also a folder in htdocs names "restriced" should I do anything with that?

Comment: Also, there is an .htpasswd file in the forbidden folder.